# How to solve this EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT ) in c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

below is my program:

It is Program to find Dijkstra's shortest path using STL set

it may not be the fastest version of doing the same job, but I have tried my best to fulfil what I need to do... just don't know why encounter the segmentation fault... and I don't know how to identify the point that the error come from... thanks for helping!

I found that it has segmentation error while running (EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT )), how can I fix it? 
Thanks for answering my question!!

```
main.cpp

// Program to find Dijkstra's shortest path using STL set
#include<iostream>
#include"graph.h"
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<list>
#include<set>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
# define INF 0x3f3f3f3f

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, int w)
{
adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, w));
adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u, w));
}

// Prints shortest paths from src to all other vertices
vector<int> Graph::shortestPath(int src)
{
// Create a set to store vertices that are being
// prerocessed
set< pair<int, int> > setds;

// Create a vector for distances and initialize all
// distances as infinite (INF)
vector<int> dist(V, INF);

// Insert source itself in Set and initialize its
// distance as 0.
setds.insert(make_pair(0, src));
dist[src] = 0;

/* Looping till all shortest distance are finalized
 then setds will become empty */
while (!setds.empty())
{
    // The first vertex in Set is the minimum distance
    // vertex, extract it from set.
    pair<int, int> tmp = *(setds.begin());
    setds.erase(setds.begin());

    // vertex label is stored in second of pair (it
    // has to be done this way to keep the vertices
    // sorted distance (distance must be first item
    // in pair)
    int u = tmp.second;

    // 'i' is used to get all adjacent vertices of a vertex
    list< pair<int, int> >::iterator i;
    for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i)
    {
        // Get vertex label and weight of current adjacent of u.
        int v = (*i).first;
        int weight = (*i).second;

        //  If there is shorter path to v through u.
        if (dist[v] > dist[u] + weight)
        {
            /*  If distance of v is not INF then it must be in
             our set, so removing it and inserting again
             with updated less distance.
             Note : We extract only those vertices from Set
             for which distance is finalized. So for them,
             we would never reach here.  */
            if (dist[v] != INF)
                setds.erase(setds.find(make_pair(dist[v], v)));

            // Updating distance of v
            dist[v] = dist[u] + weight;
            setds.insert(make_pair(dist[v], v));
        }
    }
}

// Print shortest distances stored in dist[]
//printf("Vertex   Distance from Source\n");
//for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
  //  printf("%d \t\t %d\n", i, dist[i]);

return dist;
}

// Driver program to test methods of graph class
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// create the graph given in above fugure

string Vm;
cin >> Vm;
istringstream ss(Vm);
string tokenVm;
int V, m;

std::getline(ss, tokenVm, ',');
V = stoi(tokenVm);
std::getline(ss, tokenVm, ',');
m = stoi(tokenVm);

int k;
cin >> k;

Graph g(V);

string id;
cin >> id;
istringstream sss(id);
string tokenid;
int list[k];
int i=0;

while(std::getline(sss, tokenid, ',')){
    list[i] = stoi(tokenid) << '\n';
    i++;
}

for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    istringstream ssss(input);
    string tokeninput;
    int a,b,w;

    std::getline(ssss, tokeninput, ',');
    a = stoi(tokeninput);
    std::getline(ssss, tokeninput, ',');
    b = stoi(tokeninput);
    std::getline(ssss, tokeninput, ',');
    w = stoi(tokeninput);

    // read edge and insert it to graph
    g.addEdge(a, b, w);
}

string section;
cin >> section;
if(section == "NearestGasStation"){
    int shortest;
    cin >> shortest;

    int temp = g.shortestPath(shortest)[list[0]];
    for(int i=1 ; i<k; i++){
        if ( g.shortestPath(shortest)[list[i]] < temp ){
            temp = g.shortestPath(shortest)[list[i]];
        }
    }
    cout << temp << endl;

} else if (section == "ReverseNeighbors"){
    int u;
    cin >> u;

} else {
    cout << "wrong input file!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

return 0;
}
```

and the graph.h file.

```
#ifndef graph_h
#define graph_h
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<list>
#include<set>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>

class Graph
{
int V;

std::list< std::pair<int, int> > *adj;

public:
Graph(int V);  // Constructor

void addEdge(int u, int v, int w);
std::vector<int> shortestPath(int s);
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
this->V = V;
adj = new std::list< std::pair<int, int> >[V];
}



#endif /* graph_h */
```

Comment: It doesn't seem absolutely necessary that Graph::adj is a pointer.  It could just as easily be a vector.  Then you can ensure your access to the vector is good by using vector<>::at instead of vector<>operator [].

Comment: how could I run your code? what inputs do you use?

Comment: That's a lot of code. Have you tested that your Graph implementation is bulletproof? Oh wait. You built the two into each other. Bit of a bad idea that. Now you have to debug both simultaneously.

Comment: Use std::vector for adj. Use at() instead of [] to access the elements. You know, that array indexes start at 0?

Comment: I agree -- sprinkle your code with calls to `at()` instead of `[ ]`.  If you get a `std::out_of_range` exception, then that is just one issue you need to correct and that is getting your indices within bounds.  And why did you do this: `std::list< std::pair<int, int> > *adj;` when you know you could have easily done this: `std::vector<std::list< std::pair<int, int>>> adj;`? Using `std::vector` eliminates the call to `new`, as all you're doing if you look carefully is creating a vector of `std::list`.  Removing all calls to dynamic memory allocation makes the job of debugging easier.

Comment: In addition, don't call your variables the same name as container types.  For example, you have `list` as a variable name, and at the same time, using `std::list`.  The code will look confusing, even if it does compile.  As to using `list`, this code is not valid C++: `int list[k];`  You cannot declare an array using a variable to denote the number of entries.  But you're using vector already, so why don't you use it here also?  `std::vector<int> myList(k);`.

Comment: I have changed adj to vector and list to vector myList, but it still doesnt work.

error message: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector
(lldb) "

thanks for y'all suggestion tho! Im still very new in coding... ive learnt a lot from you all.